# How to reset the force quit window's dimensions

Tags: window-manager, force-quit

my force quit window accidentally resized itself so it's wide. It's not taking up the whole screen but apparantally this is the least wide it can get.

This it what it looks like right now

[image]

It can't get any less wider than that, and I've seen it with my own eyes that the force quit window was smaller before.

It may look like a small deal, but it really amplifies when you put yourself in my shoes.

I use macos high sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just grab it by any corner or edge & drag.

The cursor doesn't change to an arrow like with most windows, but otherwise it behaves just the same way.
Opt/drag will resize as a mirror of whichever side/corner you drag [useful for if you ever lose one side off-screen.

Comment: This is confusing, I got it to work then I dragged it back out, and suddenly its not wanting to resize itself again. Then, I gave up and tried again a minute later than it worked again?

Comment: Yeah it's doing this on an M1 Big Sur as well, no cursor indicator showing you can resize the window but you most assuredly can resize it.  That would be a very old cosmetic bug that Apple really should fix.